# How to create multiple devices automatically in Thingsboard and post telemetry data using HTTP Api

Tags: http, access-token, thingsboard

I'm using **ThingsBoard** to publish some data and I want to create multiple devices automatically using thingsBoard **Rest client API** and send JSON data (stored in a JSON file) to each one of them, I’m also writing a **JAVA** program to so but I was using only one device to send the data by copying the Access Token of the device so it can receive the data, however I don’t know how to do that if I have many devices to get the **Access token** automatically from each device.
I’ve been trying for a while to look for a simple method to do so but I’m a bit lost here.

Does anyone have an idea how can I do that.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the ThingsBoard **administration** API described in this swagger https://cloud.thingsboard.io/swagger-ui.html

A few end-points will help you achieve what you need:

- for devices already created manually, you can retrieve their credentials using

```
GET /api/device/{deviceId}/credentials
```

- for devices without credentials, you can create some using

```
POST /api/device/credentials
```

Since you're working in the context of a Java application, I assume you already have a REST client with authentication to perform these calls.

Comment: I'm actually trying to post data to multiple devices that I've already created manually in Thingsboard, so I need to parse the token in the URL 
 ` URL url2 = new URL("https://demo.thingsboard.io/api/v1/Access token/telemetry")`                                   so I'm trying to find a simple way to perform multiple http post with multiple access token

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is use GET /api/tenant/assets?type=telemetry&pageSize=10000&page=0

This will get all the devices of type telemetry, and then you can fetch the part where the token is. That request will return a list.